# AS3 Array object showing up by ordering

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

I have 3 MC on stage which are all alpha=0

```
var mcArray:Array = [mc1,mc2,mc3];
for (var j:int = 0; j < mcArray.length; j++)
{
    mcArray[j].alpha = 0;
}
```

I have one button which once I click then it will make 1 of the MC become alpha=1

```
revealBtn.buttonMode = true;
revealBtn.useHandCursor = false;
revealBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, revealClick);

function revealClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    for (var j:int = 0; j < mcArray.length; j++)
    {
        mcArray[j].alpha = 1;
    }
}
```

But with the script above it will makes all 3 MC become alpha=1.

I know that this can achieve by using below code:

```
if(mc1.alpha!=1){
mc1.alpha=1
}
if(mc2.alpha!=1){
mc2.alpha=1
}
if(mc3.alpha!=1){
mc3.alpha=1
}
```

this code will give what I want to achieve but if there is more than 3 MC the lines of script will be longer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
revealBtn.buttonMode = true;
revealBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, revealClick);

var mcArray:Array = [mc0,mc1,mc2];

function revealClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    for(var i:uint = 0; i<mcArray.length; i++){
        if(this['mc'+i].alpha !== 1){
            this['mc'+i].alpha = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: just use `mcArray[i]` instead of `this['mc' + i]`

Comment: Of course, but the this[] array is more versatile. Say I had MovieClips called, skyTVContainer, skySportsContainer, skyMoviesContainer, etc and an object called packages = {'TV':[100, 20], 'Sports':[200, 20]} etc then you can see that I can interate over the packages object (var i in packages) to get the coordinates of the various containers using this['sky'+i+'Container'].x = packages[i][0]

Comment: what i meant was, `mc0`, `mc1` and `mc2` are already in the `mcArray`. as you're iterating over it, just use `mcArray[i]` (or do a `for each`). it makes no sense to put them all in an array if you're going to just do `this['mc'+i]`. If you want to do that, just get rid of `mcArray` and change your for loop to `for( var i:int = 0; i < 2; i++ )`

Comment: doing `this['mc'+i]` also ties you into the name of the movieclip, which can change. if tomorrow you decide to call them `obj0/1/2` instead, you now need to go back and change all your loops

Answer (score 1):

No that if statement would still turn all three to alpha 1.

Which of the three do you want to set to alpha = 1 when the click is made?

You could use something like this to set alpha = 1 on the first mc in the array which does NOT have alpha = 1

```
function revealClick(event:MouseEvent):void {
    for (var j:int = 0; j < mcArray.length; j++){
        if ( mcArray[j].alpha != 1 ){
            mcArray[j].alpha = 1;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a counter.

```
var cnt : int = -1; 
function revealClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if(++cnt < mcArray.length) mcArray[cnt].alpha = 1;
}
```